# Is it ok to change the wall outlets yourself?

Tags: electrical

As an amateur, is it in order for me to change an electric outlet myself without being an electrician.
I do know a thing or two about electronics, and it's just a simple wall outlet from home.

Comment: Technically sure. Legally most places yes, but some places no. What country /state /city?

Comment: Romania, European Union.

Comment: I'm paranoid not to let the wires loose, that is not deep enough into the socket and cause a fire hazard.

Comment: Yes, it's ok legally. Maybe ok depending on your skill level. Re your comment about the not deep enough socket, this seems to be more about your actual question? If so, make clear your question.

Comment: I don’t know your laws inthe US most states it is legal for a homeowner to do all of their maintenance, replacing a receptacle is one of the easier jobs to do. Turn the power off on that circuit and then it is normally a simple job of marking the wires removing them from 1 receptacle and putting them on a new one. Actually quite simple. On the receptacles on this side of the pond there is normally a strip gauge on the receptacle or the instructions on the box provide the length of wire to strip and the torque for the screws. If you provide the model of the receptacle we can walk you through it

Comment: Ack Ed Beal It's ok, I did if before, I'm just paranoid not to happen this:
https://youtu.be/kuDfDWUrEus?t=45